# Error while running a test class NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable approval process was found

Tags: unit-test

Can any one help me out with this error
when i have added this lines in the code the system throwed an error

```
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                       req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
                       req1.setObjectId(getid);
                       req1.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{userid });
                       Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
```

Error Message :

```
System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable approval process was found
```

Part of Test Class :

```
@isTest
public class Test_ApprovalProcessLeadController {
   Public static testMethod void sapld() {

        user u =[select id,Profile_Name__c from user  limit 1]; 
        lead l = new lead();
        l.lastname='Test';
        l.company='test';
        l.email='abc@test.com';       
        l.Approval_flag__c=false; 
        l.Rep_Managing_Partner__c= u.id;
        l.Approval_Status__c='Pending Approval';   
        insert l;
         System.AssertEquals(l.Id!=null,True);
         ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id', l.id);
         ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(l);         
         ApprovalProcessLeadController a = new ApprovalProcessLeadController(controller);
            test.startTest();
            a.getdetails();
            a.Redirect();
            test.stoptest();
        }
```

The Approval process is very well Activate ,but the entry criteria is written on a formula field(CheckCreatedByProfile1__c -field).How to call a formula field in a test class.

Formula field : CheckCreatedByProfile1__c -
Formulae is IF( Owner:User.Profile.Id = '00e50000000sH', true, false)

```
Approval Process Entry Criteria  :
Lead: CheckCreatedByProfileEQUALSTrue
```

Any suggestion please.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you include the full criteria?

Comment: @ Adrian Larson:Thanks for your response.I have added the entry criteria of approval process.Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error is completely related to trying a record to submit for approval process which is not meeting any approval criteria.

You must create record which has field values set meeting approval criteria. That's all need to be done.